# Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, windows-8.1

When I run

```
rails new project
```

to make new project in Ruby on rails on my PC.

It works fine. 
Then I run `bundle install` and it throws this error:

```
create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep  
run  bundle install
```

> Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will
>       break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
>
> Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
>
> Retrying source fetch due to error (2/3): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https:// rubygems.org/
>
> Retrying source fetch due to error (3/3): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https:// rubygems.org/

When I try run my project it throws this error:

> c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:352:in
>       `resolve': Could not find gem 'rails (= 4.1.1) x86-mingw32' in the
>       gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Have you tried installing the `rails` gem using `gem install rails`?

Comment: I installed RailsInstaller 2.2.3 on my PC with windows 8.1 I check **PS C:\> gem install rails
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::ETIMEDOUT: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
 time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/
latest_specs.4.8.gz)**

Answer (score 3):

Are you using rails 4?
check your Gemfile and replace

```
 source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

to

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reboot your machine , mainly if you are working with vagrant, or also  if you have any firewall. They may could have a block thread

Answer (score 0):

You should update your bundler. You are using 1.6.2 and there is a bugfix for the sudo warning in 1.6.3.

https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2984

https://github.com/bundler/bundler/commit/2cc46c7dd95988659fdb00b9aa00a73295caf130

Comment: I update bundler to 1.6.3 and have still this error **run  bundle install
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Retrying source fetch due to error (2/3): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
Retrying source fetch due to error (3/3): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/** without that root quote...

Answer (score -1):

My solution for this problem was search and replace https for http protocol on all Gemfile on folder c:/RailsInstaller/

search for:
"source 'https://rubygems.org'"

replace for:
"source 'http://rubygems.org'"

Hope this help. :)